# find the html's body without beautiful soup?

Tags: python, regex, recompile

I have been tried to find the something with beautiful soup
But now I'm curious to find the  without beautifulsoup

with recompile method How should I find the

> import re

```
</head>  
<body>
<a href="https://programmers.co.kr/learn/courses/4673"></a>#!MuziMuzi!)jayg07con&&

</body>
```

I tried

```
re.findall('<body>(.*?)</body>', html, re.DOTALL)
```

but nothing to find

Comment: Read this warning, and beware :)  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 0):

If you have to, it seems it might be just missing the `r`:

```
import re

exp = """

</head>  
<body>
<a href="https://programmers.co.kr/learn/courses/4673"></a>#!MuziMuzi!)jayg07con&&

</body>
"""

print(re.findall(r"<body>(.*?)</body>", exp ,re.DOTALL))
```

#### Output

```
['\n<a href="https://programmers.co.kr/learn/courses/4673"></a>#!MuziMuzi!)jayg07con&&\n\n']
```